# Python Error during execution

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to fetch website's data using beautiful soup, its running perfect for first 4-5 queries but after that I get this error:

```
Description:  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./r.py", line 11, in <module>
print "Description: ",k.text
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://websitename.com')
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for i in  soup.findAll("div", {"class": "ParentDiv"}):
        for j in  i.findAll("a",limit=1):
                print "Name is: ",j.text
        for k in i.findAll("div", {"class":"description"},limit=1):
                print "Description: ",k.text
        for l in i.findAll("div", {"class":"Information"},limit=1):
                print "Addition info",l.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decode something that is in your `html` variable, because at the moment BF considers it ascii, and it apparently isn't.

Decodings are pain in the back - if you dont have to use urllib, try [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), usually they are able to deocde data for you.

Comment: python get-pip.py
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-1.5-py2.6.egg
Cleaning up...
I'm unable to use pip to install requests, any other idea?

Comment: Other ways of installing them? easy_install perhaps, or setup.py from their repository?